# Ubuntu 18.04: Dropdown "places" menu in gnome-session-flashback "Computer" does not work?

Tags: compiz, 18.04, places, gnome-session-fallback

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-session-flashback compiz**. When in **top panel** I go to **Places>Computer** and click on **File System** nothing happens. What to do?

[image]